# angular js trouble in displaying div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an angular app for authenticating user, which contacts a webservice 
for authentication. Webservice returns a json in which if the user is authenticated, i route the user to a page. If not, i display a hidden div.

The problem is, it works fine for the first time. say, the user entered invalid credentials, the div gets displayed. if the user enters invalid credentials again, nothing happens. But, json from server is received. alert(); is working fine.. but displaying div works only once. How can i achieve this for any number of fail entries? .
Thanks for your help.. posting snippets.

```
login.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http)
 { 
    $scope.credentials = {};
    var popFailmessage = function(){
       //function for displaying div
         $("#danger-alert").show();
            $("#danger-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
           $("#danger-alert").alert('close');

            }); 
    }
     $scope.authenticate = function(user){
         var credentials = user;// angular.copy(user);
    $http({
method: "GET",
url: "http://localhost:8000/index/action",
params: {
    email : credentials.email,
    password : credentials.password
}
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
    console.log(data);
        if(data ==  0){
            popFailmessage(); //calling method here

        }else{
            //redirect to some page
        }
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
        console.log(data);
    });


    }


 });
```

And the HTML part..

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="danger-alert" style="display:none">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
<center> <strong>Login Failed!  </strong>
Please check your ID/ Password.</center>
```

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: This is only part of the code, there isn't enough information here for others to replicate the problem and debug your logic.  You should update your question to include a [mcve] of the issue, preferably using something like plunker.  Aside from that, you are asking why angular isn't showing a popup, but the function isn't angular.  `$` is JQuery.

Comment: if I had to guess, not being an expert on JQuery, my first guess would be that you are not creating a new div each time, you are trying to re-use the existing one, and you have used an invalid syntax for your `.fadeTo()` function (second parameter, opacity, is valid from `0` to `1`, but you have `500`), and so the div disappears, and doesn't reappear the next time you try to show it.

Comment: @Claies I just told, its an angular app.. this is most of it.. the core logic.. i fire an ajax and im getting data. post getting im not able to display divs using jquery. As said earlier, it works fine for first time and then does not respond..but i can see data from server (console.log). ..i think ive included everything.. from calling the webservice to displaying the div.

Comment: it may be an angular app, but your problem is ***definitely*** with non angular JQuery bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pavan, you can try the following code:

```
var popFailmessage = function(){
   //function for displaying div
     $("#danger-alert").show();
        $("#danger-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
            $("#danger-alert").alert('close');
            $("#danger-alert").hide();
        }); 
}
```

It should work.

Comment: check the console, whether you are getting any errors as follows:
    $(...).alert is not a function

If yes, then try after commenting the following line
    $("#danger-alert").alert('close');

Comment: @Pavan, still can you comment this line and try again??
Because i am getting error on my console.

Comment: @J S.. i dint get any error.. but i commented that line. IT WORKED!..thanks alot!